# Use a variable value inside SELECT statement in sql,php

Tags: php, sql, select, echo

Hi there I'am trying to filter my sql comments results by property name in a property rental company website.

I Have everything working good, the thing is that the property name is displayed dynamicly  by this line depending on the property link you click

```
<?php echo $objProperty->pro_name ?>  and this gives me "Costa Vida"
```

And I want that same result to replace 'Costa Vida' in this line

```
$sql="SELECT * from review WHERE status=1 AND proj_desc='Costa Vida' ORDER BY clients_id DESC limit $offset, $limit";
```

How Can I Implement the first line or an echo to proj_desc='' in a similar way of the first line of code I'm very new to this.

I hope I made my self clear with my problem I Hope it has a simple solution and not use much of your time.

Thanks in Advance
Victor C

Comment: do you men like this? $sql="SELECT * from review WHERE status=1 AND proj_desc='".$objProperty->pro_name."' ORDER BY clients_id DESC limit $offset, $limit";

Comment: Just Like that man thanks it worked like a charm, thanks again and sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work!

```
$proj_desc=$objProperty->pro_name;
$sql = "SELECT * from review WHERE status=1 AND proj_desc= $proj_desc ORDER BY clients_id DESC limit $offset, $limit";
```